# Need a tkinter gui to simulate ENTER key press

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a button using tkinter to simulate the ENTER key on the keyboard. The reason I need this is because the final GUI will be displayed on a touchscreen. There will be no keyboard.

My parent process is calling a command where if the enter key is pressed, it will turn on a light. I need the light to be turned on every time the enter button is pressed. The command called is programmed to only accept the enter key on the keyboard and I cannot do anything to change it.

If this makes sense, I appreciate all help I can get.

Here is the body of the code that I have:

```
import subprocess
import Tkinter

class X:

    def __init__(self):
    .....

    def __createGUI(self, ):
            self.light = Tkinter.Button(Window, text="Start", command=self.Start)
            self.light.grid()
            self.light = Tkinter.Button(Window, text="Light", command=self.Light)
            self.light.bind('<Return>') # Is this what I need tp do it?
            self.light.grid()

     def Start(self)
          command = "....." #This line of code sends a command to call a separate      program. In this program if the Enter key on the keyboard is pressed the light will turn on. This program cannot be changed
          self.p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr.......)
          .....

     def Light(self)
         #I have nothing for this so far.... maybe a return "Enter" command to Start

if __name__== "__main__":
      ....
      ....
```

So, what I need is a GUI button, that when it is clicked, tells Start that Enter has been clicked. Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output,stderror = self.p.communicate("\r")`

maybe what you are looking for ... communicate sends commands to a process ... not sure if the program is looking for \r, \n or is actually listening for an enter event ... if its actually listening for an enter event that is going to get alot harder

if you want to send data and continue writing I believe you can do something like

```
self.p.stdin.write("\r")
```

if that doesnt work you may need to spawn a thread to handle the communication part ...

Comment: This worked but Light seems to be stuck until the program is terminated. Which from what I've read, is the way communicate works. Is there a way to change that? For it to end after one cycle.